# Rails - How to auto-transfer records from table to table at a specific time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am pre-storing records in a table `A` and I want to transfer these records from table `A` to table `B` automatically at a specific time, lets say on every evening at 08:00 PM.

Any ideas on how to solve this little problem?

Comment: If your hosting supports cronjobs (or something similar): Create a script to do this transfer and schedule a cronjob at whatever time you want the transfer to happen.

Comment: Try this [GEM](https://rubygems.org/gems/rufus-scheduler/versions/3.0.9)

Comment: create rake task in your app

Comment: use `whenever` gem. but if your host provides more jobs to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create rake task to implement your job, and then schedule it with  **cron**, default *nix time manager. Its syntax is difficult to remember, so I prefer to use Ruby wrapper around it, [gem whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)  gem to run cron jobs ...for example job that runs  every 5 mins

**in schedule.rb**

```
every 5.minutes do
rake "transfer_data:send_data"
end
```

**lib/tasks/send_data.rake**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

namespace :transfer_data do
  desc "Rake task to transfer data
  task :send_data => :environment do
## code to transfer data from one table to other table 
end
end
```

Execute the task using `bundle exec rake transfer_data:send_data`